# ME2: Loyalty booleans?

Tags: mass-effect-2

I'm tired playing ME2 but I have to record the plot. There's no gameplays in my language with choices I like. Can I just change some variables and boom, have done every loyalty mission ? Or it's impossible ?

Comment: This question is actually more about mass-effect-3 than mass-effect-2 as it will be save data you are wanting to edit from 2 to use in 3, right?  Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Following op on what @BlackVegetable said, what do you mean by "I have to record the plot"? Are you just getting a save game ready for ME3?

Comment: I'm recording the gameplay for my language (nothing on YT with my choices), and I'm playing for the plot so I connected it and made "record the plot". XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this easily with Gibbed's Save Editor by editing the appropriate values ("X is loyal") in either your [ME2](http://social.bioware.com/project/4373/#files) or [ME3](http://svn.gib.me/builds/masseffect3/?C=M;O=D) save file.  Below are screenshots showing where to access these values in each tool respectively.

[image: screenshot ME2]

[image: screenshot ME3]